# query with a reference condition

Tags: apex, soql, query

I have a query inside a trigger and one of the conditions is that a reference field (lookup) is not null.
My query is:

```
List<Contract> contratti=[Select Id,Opportunitl__c from Contract 
        where Id IN: Trigger.new AND Opportunitl__c !=null ];
```

where Opportunitl__c is the reference field, but it's not working. The list "contratti" contains Contracts with an empty Opportunitl__c. What is wrong in this query?

Comment: try `Opportunitl__r.Id` instead or `Opportunitl__c`

Comment: already tried and didn't work

Comment: What do you mean by "it's not working"? What is the actual problem or error message that you're getting?

Comment: the problem is:  the List contratti contains also  contracts where the reference Opportunitl__c is empty and I dont' want that type of Contract inside the list

Comment: May be you just need to write query as /* List<Contract> contratti=[Select Id,Opportunitl__c from Contract 
        where  Opportunitl__c !=null ]; */ Just removed the condition first condition in the query

Comment: did it, but same result Contract whit null reference field inside the list

Comment: What object is the trigger acting upon?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, the best way to do that is to not use a query at all. Just loop through the trigger.new and retrieve the Contracts you need.

```
List<Contract> contratti = new List<Contract>();
for(Contract contratto : Trigger.new){
    if(contratto.Opportunitl__c != null) contratti.add(contratto);
}
```

If, form some reason, you still need the query. You can't compare with `null`. Change it to

```
List<Contract> contratti=[Select Id,Opportunitl__c from Contract 
    where Id IN: Trigger.new AND Opportunitl__c != ''];
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this query it may help to you.

```
List<Contract> contratti = [Select Id,Opportunitl__c from Contract where Id IN :Trigger.newMap.keySet() AND Opportunitl__c != NULL];
```

Incase if failure this query you can try in this method

```
Set<Id> conIds = Trigger.newMap.keySet();
List<Contract> contratti = [Select Id,Opportunitl__c from Contract where Id IN :conIds AND Opportunitl__c != NULL];
```